# New MVC 5 web API system using existing separate identity login system

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am creating a new web API system which does not have its own login system. This new web API will have to use an existing system already with ASP.NET Core Identity.

How can the new system utilize the existing identity login?

Framework: ASPNet core 5

Comment: Please review the answer below. Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can Scaffold Identify after creating the .NET 5 WEB API. Please refer to the URL and images below.

URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

[image]

[image]